# Function call missing argument list error (c++)

Tags: c++

I created Windows Forms app and I have problem with this code can somebody help me with this ? Thanks for help.

```
    void thListen(void* Args)
        {
            const char* chIp;
            long answer; 
            WSAData wsaData;
            WORD DLLVERSION;
            DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2,1);
            answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &wsaData); // odpowiadanie za uzywanie wersji winsocket
            SOCKADDR_IN addr; // deklarowanie obiekut 
            int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
            SOCKET sListen;
            SOCKET sConnect; 
            sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

            chIp = (const char*)(void*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox1->Text);

            addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(chIp); 
            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                     
            addr.sin_port = htons(1234);                
            sListen = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, NULL);   
            bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); 
            listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);
            for(;;)
            {
                if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)) 
                {
                    answer = send(sConnect, "Wiadomosc",10 , NULL); 
                }
            }
            _endthread();
        }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 _beginthread(this->thListen, 0, NULL);
             }
    };
}
```

Problem is with `this->thListen` and error is `Error    1   error C3867: 'WinSockCommunicationApplication::Form1::thListen': function call missing argument list; use '&WinSockCommunicationApplication::Form1::thListen' to create a pointer to member c:\users\bartek\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\winsockcommunicationapplication\winsockcommunicationapplication\Form1.h   139 1   WinSockCommunicationApplication (Visual Studio 2010)`
  I can put there () what I shoud do ?

Comment: I mean, really. The error spells it out in plain English. It can't do much better.

Answer (score 2):

Do what it tells you to do and replace

```
_beginthread(this->thListen, 0, NULL);
```

By

```
_beginthread(&WinSockCommunicationApplication::Form1::thListen, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks body but I can't do this maybe I don't know what else do but if I put this _beginthread(&WinSockCommunicationApplication::Form1::thListen, 0, NULL); in a code I have next error called : a pointer-tomember is not valid for a managed class